# How to access a public function in solidity?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle

I have a smart contract deployed on the Testnet here -

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xD99ea28F24317F28291556754edd24AA1352c26e

This contract has a public function triggerAgeCount

```
   function increaseAge() internal {
     totalSupply += 1;
     balaceOf[owner] += 1;
   }

function triggerAgeCount() public {
    if ( (now-creationTime) >= 365 days ){
        increaseAge();
        creationTime = now;

    }
}
```

I want to know how can I trigger this event once the contract is deployed, also where can I check the totalSupply for the current contract.

The whole code is

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0;

contract Jeevan{

   string public constant name = "Jeevan";
   string public constant symbol = "JA";
   uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
   uint public totalSupply = 30;
   uint256 public creationTime = now;
   address owner;

   mapping(address => uint256) public balaceOf;

    constructor() public{
       balaceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
       owner = msg.sender;
   }

   event balanceTransferred(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value);

 function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) internal{
    require(_to !=_from);
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(balaceOf[_from] >= _value);
    uint previousBalance = (balaceOf[_from] + balaceOf[_to]);
    balaceOf[_from] -= _value;
    balaceOf[_to] += _value;
    assert(balaceOf[_from]+balaceOf[_to] == previousBalance);
 }

   function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
       _transfer(msg.sender,_to,_value);
       emit balanceTransferred(msg.sender,_to, _value);
   }

   function increaseAge() internal {
     totalSupply += 1;
     balaceOf[owner] += 1;
   }

function triggerAgeCount() public {
    if ( (now-creationTime) >= 365 days ){
        increaseAge();
        creationTime = now;

    }
}

}
```

I want that after every 365 days, I call the triggerAgeCount() function and it increase the totalSupply by +1.

Comment: `how can I trigger this event` - what event?

Comment: `where can I check the totalSupply for the current contract` - what is "totalSupply"?

Comment: `This contract has a public function triggerAgeCount` - so how exactly is that piece of information relevant to anything of what you're asking???

Comment: I want to call the '''function triggerAgeCount() public'''. totalSupply is the total number of token in this contract, the token name is JA.

Comment: I have added the whole code in the question above

Comment: The compiler generates a getter function for `uint public totalSupply`, of the exact same name, i.e., `function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256)`. So you can simply call that function.

Comment: `I want that after every 365 days, I call the triggerAgeCount() function and it increase the totalSupply by +1` - so what's stopping you from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Himanshu I am also learning Solidity.  You can do what you are asking for from Remix in the Deploy tab.   http://remix.ethereum.org/

[image: Remix]